# c# datagridview datasource

Tags: c#, gridview

I am creating a Datagridview programmatically in a dll file.
It's datasource is a Datatable, and my code is as such:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(rdr);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Why then when I check how many columns and rows the datagrid has, it shows as nothing.  Although, when I do the same check on the Datatable it shows that there is data.
Does the gridview need to be actually on a form for it to be populated?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in WinForms or WPF or what ?!

Comment: so `dgv.Rows.Count` and `dgv.Columns.Count` are returning 0?

Comment: A DataGridView is windorms.  In ASP.NET it's just a GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it does.  I created a new WinForms app, copied your code into the Form_Load event, and added these two lines immediately after your code and got results.

```
this.Controls.Add(dgv);
MessageBox.Show(dgv.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

If I comment out the first line the count is 0.